# PHP Javascript: Closing Popup calling parent window in background

Tags: javascript, php

Let's say a parent window is `www.mysite.com/index.php` has several links. When user clicks on these links, a popup is opened.

The popup has some forms. When the user clicks submit button, another script is called within the popup like this:

```
if ((isset($_POST['Complete'])) && ($_POST['Complete']=='Complete')) {
    unset($_POST['Complete']);

    include 'result.php';

    return;
}
```

The `result.php` enters the data into database and pass the result to parent window with the following

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    window.opener.location.href = 'submission.php';
    window.close();
</script>
```

The parent window then show the final result, update the master database and emails the users.

Now here is the problem.

1. User clicks the link on parents.
2. Form opens, but user click close (browser cross button).
3. The user then closes parent window
4. The user then visit some other page of the site; say other.php
5. But the master database is getting updated and the user is getting the email (All `null` values though).

Since the form was never completed, the `result.php` should never be called. and if `result.php` is never called, submission.php should never be called.

What is happening here?

Comment: Hi again. i have studied the problem for hours. i have stepped out a scenario which is creating the anomaly in 100% cases. Temporarily, i have put another check the submission.php which first check whether the result.php has inserted any record in the db. if there is no record, a invalid submission entry will be passed. Now this has improved the user experiences but this is not a solution. why would this happen?!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Change the type  of the close button to button.